# How long value convert into ARGB color?

Tags: c#, converters, argb

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{ 
    string userColourString = value.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(userColourString);
    long userColourNumeric = 0; 
    Int64.TryParse(userColourString, out userColourNumeric); 
    var colourToUse = userColourNumeric;
    return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(string.Format("#{0:x6}", colourToUse));
}
```

I'm trying to convert the following two values into colours by using the converter method above but it's not working,.
    -2147483630
    16777215

Comment: There is no error on ur code, check your values again.

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your reply.  &H80000012 = -2147483630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `16777215` decimal converts to `FFFFFF` hexadecimal. I tested your code, and the value of `colourToUse` is indeed `"#ffffff"`. That will easily convert to the color White.

The value `-2147483630` decimal ends up being converted to `FFFFFFFF80000012` hexadecimal. I'm not sure what color you're hoping that'll convert to. No wonder the `ConvertFromString` method throws a format exception.

---

You added that you're referencing an old chart of [VB6 color constants](http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Color_Constants_/_Color_Forms_/_Controls_/_Transparency_VB6).

In order to generate the colors in that chart, you'll need to use `ColorTranslator.FromWin32`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var userColourString = value.ToString();
    int userColourNumeric = 0;
    int.TryParse(userColourString, out userColourNumeric);
    var colourToUse = userColourNumeric;
    return ColorTranslator.FromWin32(colourToUse);
}
```

Comment: The -2147483630=&H80000012 this is the value list.  http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Color_Constants_/_Color_Forms_/_Controls_/_Transparency_VB6

Comment: the reason is i am working on old vb6 project and rewrite that project into c#.  both project are  need to be work simultaneously. that -2147483630 value are still use in vb6 user.and i have to use same database for get value :(

Comment: i am using System.Windows.Media  because TargetType is "System.Windows.Media". Your  "ColorTranslator" is from System.Drawing. if you can give one small hint to do this color converter using System.Windows.Media it's more helpfull. thank you.